# What is the meaning of routerLinkActiveOptions?

Tags: angular

I found some navigation bar code.
In the first list element i know that routerLinkActive will give the active class when the link is clicked.
But in the second list element i dont understant the meaninf of
  [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact : true}"

What is is doing?

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link"
         [routerLink]="['/welcome']"
         routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link"
         [routerLink]="['/products']"
         routerLinkActive="active"
         [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact : true}">Product List</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: From the official docs: `You can configure RouterLinkActive by passing exact: true. This will add the classes only when the url matches the link exactly.` https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive#routerLinkActiveOptions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{ exact: true }` will match **only** the route in `routerLink`.

If you have the link without exact specified or set to false:

```
<a class="nav-link"
  [routerLink]="['/products']"
  routerLinkActive="active">
  Product List
</a>
```

The active class would be added to the link for the following example urls:

- /products
- /products?sort=price
- /products/55

With exact set to true only /products would be matched.